# The Guys - Logic #2 : Ways to work

Tags: logical-deduction, logic-grid

[image: The Guys]

So the guys are back. This time, they decide to change up their way to work. Let's see what they're up to...

**Start the two minute timer...**

**1.** Since Anthony and Charles weren't taking the bus today, Michael decided to do a little reading during the 1320 feet to work.

**2.** Charles didn't walk the half mile to work.

Based on those two statements, figure out how the guys got to work by walking, running, or bus - and the distance they had to travel: quarter, half, and 1 mile.

[image: The Guys]

Answer (score 1):

From (1)

> Michael bus .25 mile

From (2) w/o bus

> Charles runs 1 mile

The rest

> Anthony walks .5 mile

Comment: Technically all (2) tells us is rot13(gung rvgure Puneyrf qvqa'g jnyx, be qvqa'g geniry ½ zvyr, be obgu - juvpu yrnirf hf va gur hasbeghangr cbfvgvba bs abg npghnyyl orvat noyr gb qrpvqr nalguvat orlbaq jung (1) gbyq hf).

Comment: I agree with Rubio here. If quoted line number 2 without context I would assume Charles lives half mile from work and decided not to walk that distance.